# the next button cannot function before all input forms are filled in multiple form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The code JS :

```
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){

  if(animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

  //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

  //show the next fieldset
  next_fs.show(); 

  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
    //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
    //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
    scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
    //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
    left = (now * 50)+"%";
    //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
    opacity = 1 - now;
    current_fs.css({
      'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
      'position': 'absolute'
    });
  next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
}, 
duration: 800, 
complete: function(){
  current_fs.hide();
  animating = false;
}, 
//this comes from the custom easing plugin
easing: 'easeInOutBack'
});
});
```

I use the template is https://codepen.io/atakan/pen/gqbIz

I want when the next button input form is filled in all, if not the next button cannot function before all input forms are filled.

Please help me to modify the JS in https://codepen.io/atakan/pen/gqbIz . Thank You

Comment: One warning: NEVER call anything submit in a form

Comment: Why not use a form validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding below JS script next to **$(".next").click(function(){** will validate form fields. Make sure to add Id attribute in each field sets.

```
Example: <fieldset id="f1">, <fieldset id="f2"> and <fieldset id="f3">

_p_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');    
$('#msform #'+ _p_id + ' input').each(function(){
    if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
        isFormValid = false;
        return false;
    }else{
        isFormValid = true;
    }
});
if(!isFormValid){
    return false;
}
```